# Increment value count of key-value pairs in spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I'm new to spark & scala and I'm trying to increment the value of a key-value pair in a column using a value from another column.

Below is the input DataFrame.

```
val inputDF = Seq(
(1, "Visa", 1, None), 
(2, "MC", 2, Some("Visa -> 1")), 
(3, "Amex", 1, None), 
(4, "Amex", 3, Some("Visa -> 1, MC -> 1")), 
(5, "Amex", 4, Some("Visa -> 2, MC -> 1")),
(6, "MC", 1, None), 
(7, "Visa", 5, Some("Visa -> 2, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1")), 
(8, "Visa", 6, Some("Visa -> 2, MC -> 2, Amex -> 1")), 
(9, "MC", 1, None),
(10, "MC", 2, Some("Amex -> 1"))).toDF("person_id", "card_type", "number_of_cards", "card_type_details")

+---------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|person_id|card_type|number_of_cards|card_type_details            |
+---------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|1        |Visa     |1              |null                         |
|2        |MC       |2              |Visa -> 1                    |
|3        |Amex     |1              |null                         |
|4        |Amex     |3              |Visa -> 1, MC -> 1           |
|5        |Amex     |4              |Visa -> 2, MC -> 1           |
|6        |MC       |1              |null                         |
|7        |Visa     |5              |Visa -> 2, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1|
|8        |Visa     |6              |Visa -> 2, MC -> 2, Amex -> 1|
|9        |MC       |1              |null                         |
|10       |MC       |2              |Amex -> 1                    |
+---------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

Now from the above input, if the value of card_type_details is null, then get the value from card_type and add -> 1 (Like the first row).

If the value of card_type_details is not null, then check if card_type already exists as a key in  card_type_details. If yes, then increment the value of the corresponding key by 1 else, add a new key-value pair (Like second and seventh row).

Below is the Expected Output:

```
val expectedOutputDF = Seq(
(1, "Visa", 1, Some("Visa -> 1")), 
(2, "MC", 2, Some("Visa -> 1, MC -> 1")), 
(3, "Amex", 1, Some("Amex -> 1")), 
(4, "Amex", 3, Some("Visa -> 1, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1")), 
(5, "Amex", 4, Some("Visa -> 2, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1")),
(6, "MC", 1, Some("MC -> 1")), 
(7, "Visa", 5, Some("Visa -> 3, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1")), 
(8, "Visa", 6, Some("Visa -> 3, MC -> 2, Amex -> 1")), 
(9, "MC", 1, Some("MC -> 1")),
(10, "MC", 2, Some("Amex -> 1, MC -> 1"))).toDF("person_id", "card_type", "number_of_cards", "card_type_details")

+---------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|person_id|card_type|number_of_cards|card_type_details            |
+---------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|1        |Visa     |1              |Visa -> 1                    |
|2        |MC       |2              |Visa -> 1, MC -> 1           |
|3        |Amex     |1              |Amex -> 1                    |
|4        |Amex     |3              |Visa -> 1, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1|
|5        |Amex     |4              |Visa -> 2, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1|
|6        |MC       |1              |MC -> 1                      |
|7        |Visa     |5              |Visa -> 3, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1|
|8        |Visa     |6              |Visa -> 3, MC -> 2, Amex -> 1|
|9        |MC       |1              |MC -> 1                      |
|10       |MC       |2              |Amex -> 1, MC -> 1           |
+---------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

Any suggestions on how to extract this?

Comment: what is the datatype of ```card_type_details``` column ??

Comment: @Srinivas I have considered card_type_details as String. Let's assume the final output will be written into a Cassandra table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `card_type_details` is of type `map`. Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|person_id|card_type|number_of_cards|card_type_details            |
+---------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|1        |Visa     |1              |null                         |
|2        |MC       |2              |Visa -> 1                    |
|3        |Amex     |1              |null                         |
|4        |Amex     |3              |Visa -> 1, MC -> 1           |
|5        |Amex     |4              |Visa -> 2, MC -> 1           |
|6        |MC       |1              |null                         |
|7        |Visa     |5              |Visa -> 2, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1|
|8        |Visa     |6              |Visa -> 2, MC -> 2, Amex -> 1|
|9        |MC       |1              |null                         |
|10       |MC       |2              |Amex -> 1                    |
+---------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

Creating expressions.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val colExpr = when(size($"card_type_details") === 0, map($"card_type",lit(1)))
.otherwise(
    when(
        expr("card_type_details[card_type]").isNotNull,
        map_concat(
            expr("map(card_type,card_type_details[card_type] + 1)"),
            expr("map_filter(card_type_details,(k,v) -> k != card_type)")
        )
    )
    .otherwise(map_concat($"card_type_details",map($"card_type",lit(1))))
)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

colExpr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = CASE WHEN (size(card_type_details) = 0) THEN map(card_type, 1) ELSE CASE WHEN (card_type_details[card_type] IS NOT NULL) THEN map_concat(map(card_type, (card_type_details[card_type] + 1)), map_filter(card_type_details, lambdafunction((NOT (k = card_type)), k, v))) ELSE map_concat(card_type_details, map(card_type, 1)) END END
```

```
scala> indf.withColumn("new_card_type_details",colExpr).show(false)
+---------+---------+---------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|person_id|card_type|number_of_cards|card_type_details              |new_card_type_details          |
+---------+---------+---------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|1        |Visa     |1              |[]                             |[Visa -> 1]                    |
|2        |MC       |2              |[Visa -> 1]                    |[Visa -> 1, MC -> 1]           |
|3        |Amex     |1              |[]                             |[Amex -> 1]                    |
|4        |Amex     |3              |[Visa -> 1, MC -> 1]           |[Visa -> 1, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1]|
|5        |Amex     |4              |[Visa -> 2, MC -> 1]           |[Visa -> 2, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1]|
|6        |MC       |1              |[]                             |[MC -> 1]                      |
|7        |Visa     |5              |[Visa -> 2, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1]|[Visa -> 3, MC -> 1, Amex -> 1]|
|8        |Visa     |6              |[Visa -> 2, MC -> 2, Amex -> 1]|[Visa -> 3, MC -> 2, Amex -> 1]|
|9        |MC       |1              |[]                             |[MC -> 1]                      |
|10       |MC       |2              |[Amex -> 1]                    |[Amex -> 1, MC -> 1]           |
+---------+---------+---------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Looks like id 8,9 having incorrect output values in the new_card_type_details column.

Comment: When passing the card_type_details  as map datatype in input, I'm getting different output. Attached the input and output in the below comments.

Comment: `val inputDF2 = Seq((1, "Visa", 1, Map[String, Int]()), (2, "MC", 2, Map("Visa" -> 1)), (3, "Amex", 1, Map[String, Int]()), (4, "Amex", 3, Map("Visa" -> 1, "MC" -> 1)), (5, "Amex", 4, Map("Visa" -> 2, "MC" -> 1)),(6, "MC", 1, Map[String, Int]()), (7, "Visa", 5, Map("Visa" -> 2, "MC" -> 1, "Amex" -> 1)), (8, "Visa", 6, Map("Visa" -> 2, "MC" -> 2, "Amex" -> 1)), (9, "MC", 1, Map[String, Int]()),(10, "MC", 2, Map("Amex" -> 1))).toDF("person_id", "card_type", "number_of_cards", "card_type_details")`  
  `inputDF2.withColumn("new_card_type_details",colExpr).show(false)`

Comment: No. I'm getting null in new_card_type_details columns when card_type_details is not null.

Comment: for me getting correct values, are you using updated solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223394/discussion-between-vamsi-and-srinivas).